# How to add a CAA Record on Debian

Tags: dns, openssl, ssl

I currently have a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate for my Debian server, and would like to implement CAA (Certification Authority Authorization, RFC 6844) on it.

I'm a bit confused as to how to implement it however, as I don't seem to be able to add it to my zone file on my registrar's site. (gandi.net)

Is it a file I add to the root of the web server, or do I have to wait until my registrar supports it?

Comment: Is this server hosted by gandi.net, or is gandi.net handling your domain name? If you are hosting, please tell us what you are using as the web server (apache, nginx, etc.)

Comment: I'm using nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a DNS record. If your registrar doesn't support adding it, the only alternative would be to use a different DNS provider (or run your own DNS servers).

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to contact my registrar to see if there is any way to add it manually.